# Yaml with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

i'm doing some exercises and trying to wrap my head around how to write yaml build.

```
    spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
    envFrom: 
    - configMapRef: 
        name: anotherone # the name of the config map
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

VS

```
containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
    env:
    - name: option # name of the env variable
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: options # name of config map
          key: var5 # name of the entity in config map
```

So my problem here is: When do i use '-' symbol when i make a build in kubernetes ? 
I do understand that if i apply '-' before a string it makes it an object inside a list, but i don't understand when i need to use a list in a build in kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "-" symbol is because type of field is array of objects, if type of field is string then value comes after ":" symbol. When field is object there is no "-" but list of keys of that object like you see for example in `valueFrom` . You will see sepcification of fields when you run `kubectl explain`command, for instance:

```
 kubectl explain pod
 kubectl explain pod.spec.containers
```